# keyboard reset radiogroup value

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, radio-button, radio-group

I have a custom ListView with a radiogroup in each row.
When I change the checked radio button, I call a dialog with some edittext fields (using the onCheckedChanged() method). But, when i focused an edittext to write something, I lose all the checked radiobuttons which are **covered** by keyboard, and the group returns to the default option selected.
can someone help me?

*List adapter*

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ContractItemHolder cih = new ContractItemHolder();
    if (row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_proposals_item, parent, false);
        cih.setTvItemTitle((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemTitle));
        cih.setRgItemStatus((RadioGroup)row.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupStatus));

        row.setTag(cih);
    }else {
        cih=(ContractItemHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    final ContractItem ci = list.get(position);
    cih.getRgItemStatus().setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            groupSel = group;
            int selected = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            Dialog d;
            switch (selected) {
            case R.id.radioAccepted:
                d = createDialog(context, ACCEPTED_CODE, ci, selected);
                d.show();
                break;
            case R.id.radioRefused:
                d = createDialog(context, REFUSED_CODE, ci, selected);
                d.show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    cih.getTvItemTitle().setText(ci.getDescItem());
    return row;
}
```

*List item layout (the row..)*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/> 

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioNull"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Non Proposto" 
            android:checked="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioPending"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="In trattativa" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioAccepted"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Accettato" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/Green"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioRefused"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rifiutato" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/Red"/>

    </RadioGroup> 

</LinearLayout>
```

*Dialog impl*

```
private Dialog createDialog(Context context, final int code, ContractItem item,final int selected){ //type: refused, accepted
    d = new Dialog(context);
    d.setTitle(item.getDescItem());
    d.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog_prop);
    d.getWindow().setLayout(900, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    d.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    Button btnOK = (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.buttonPropOK);
    Button btnCancel = (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.buttonPropCancel);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            d.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            d.dismiss();

        }
    });
    return d;
}
```

*Dialog layout*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="50dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextDiscount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Sconto proposto"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerScuse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Note"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPropCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Annulla"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPropOK"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your `ListAdapter` implementation, list item layout XML file and possibly `Dialog` implementation along with its layout. also are you familiar with the concept of list-item view recycling?

Comment: i added the code. for the second question, no i'm not familiar with the concept of list-item view recycling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are partially aware of the list-item view recycling process.

The `ListView` component doesn't generate view for each item in the list. So, there won't be `15` of them in your case. There will be just as many as can fit on the screen. When you scroll the list, the old items, which are no longer visible, *are recycled*. The `getView` is then called with `convertView != null` and the adapter is giving you an opportunity to *update* this recycled item view. This is done for performance reasons - just imagine an adapter having 10000 items (not a rare thing in commercial applications). Should it create all 10000 list item views? Imagine the performance you would have while scrolling such a list...

In your `getView()` code, you update an item view only partially - you always set item title in this line:

```
cih.getTvItemTitle().setText(ci.getDescItem());
```

When an fresh item view is created (i.e. the `convertView == null`) the radio group has a default selection, which may be fine in your case.

However, when the item view is recycled (i.e. the `convertView != null`), then you:

- set a change listener in this line:

  ```
  cih.getRgItemStatus().setOnCheckedChangeListener(...);
  ```
- set item title:

  ```
  cih.getTvItemTitle().setText(ci.getDescItem());
  ```

But you never set the checked radio group item. That means, it will have a value which was last set for this instance of item view - *not for that position*. You should store that information - probably in `ContractItem`, update it when the radio group item is selected and finally - retrieve it when `convertView != null` and set selected item of the radio group to the correct value.

You probably see this defect when you open up a dialog - the visible area of a `ListView` becomes smaller as the soft keyboard opens. This causes the `ListView` to remove unnecessary (technically: no longer visible) item views. When you hide the soft keyboard, the `ListView` area becomes larger again thus causing it to create missing item views. Unfortunately, you don't save and restore the last selected item of the radio group and so, after creation the newly visible items have the default item selected in the radio group.

Comment: I have understand what the problem is and now I'm able to solve that. But after looking carrefully my layout's design, I finally decided to leave the idea to have the 4 radio buttons in the list, because it's a very orrible layout :D So, I'm going to use the Multi-Pane implementations of android design. Thanks for your help!!